# Is there an after view change hook (much like didInsertElement)?

Tags: ember.js

Using the `didInsertElement` hook, I'm able to do some jQuery plugin initialization that is needed. However, if a property changes, Ember re-renders the view, but does not call `didInsertElement` again. Presumably this is because the element is already on the DOM and only certain pieces have changed.

My question is, is there a method I can override, or some other way to access what's been rendered to the DOM by an `Ember.View` **AFTER** its actually inserted into the DOM?

I attempted to use `afterRender`, but it did not work.

Comment: Did you try `willRerender` hook ?

Comment: willRerender will not work for this

Comment: you can decompose another child view and force it in or out of the page, they you can get the didInsertElement on it ...

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a slightly unusual way of tackling this problem. You can [make a handlebars helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760733/ember-js-using-a-handlebars-helper-to-detect-that-a-subview-has-rendered/13857859#13857859) that fires an event when the view portion is re-rendered. I was using Bootstrap and jqPlot and needed to be able to tell, say, when the div was available to draw a chart into. With my helper you can do this:

```
{{#if dataIsLoaded}}
    {{trigger didRenderChartDiv}}
    <div id="chartHost"></div>
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also hook into the childViews array and observe changes on that.

Something like this works but I don't think it's a good performance practice.

```
childViewsArrayDidChange: function() {
  console.log("childViews-Array did change");
}.observes('childViews.@each')
```

Comment: Not working in Ember CLI as of posting this comment. Solution looks great, just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the question is still valid since it's been a while. but no answer was selected.
I ran into a similar problem where I want to show a form based on a controller property. Once the form is displayed I would like to run some javascript to bind event handlers.

The Javascript however did not bind the event handlers properly since the elements were not displayed when the `didInsertElement` was triggered.

My solution is the following,

**Controller & View**

```
App.FormController  = Ember.Controller.extend({

    myViewVisible : false,

    actions : {

        toggleForm : function(){
            this.toggleProperty('myViewVisible');
            console.log( this.get('myViewVisible') );
        }

    }
});

App.FormView    = Ember.View.extend({

    isVisible:function(){
        this.rerender();
    }.property('controller.myViewVisible'),

    didInsertElement : function(){
        // Do JS stuff
    }

});
```

**And the template**

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="form">
      <h2>Form</h2>
      <button {{action 'toggleForm'}}>Toggle form</button>
      {{#if myViewVisible}}
        {{partial "tform"}}
      {{else}}
      <p>Click button to show form</p>
      {{/if}}
  </script>
```

The view binds a property of the controller. Once that property changes the `isVisible` function kicks in and rerenders the view. Causing the `didInsertElement` to fire again and binding the JS code to the DOM elements that are now available.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry some [...] moderator deleted my original answer even though it was upvoted... shm

Original answer:
Take a look at this article by Yehuda Katz http://yehudakatz.com/2011/06/11/using-sproutcore-2-0-with-jquery-ui/. It's old and some of the code needs modification to work with Ember's current api, but it's a good example on how to integrate outside frameworks and plugins with Ember.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same issue like this:

```
Ember.run.sync(); //force applying bindings
//run after 100ms your code
Ember.run.later(function () {
  //your code
}, 100);
```

**EDIT**: Since this is an old answer, it might be obsolete in the current EmberJS release

Comment: Where did you put this code? And this 100ms doesn't sound like the "right" way this should be done.. I hope emberjs has a didRerenderElement hook.