# Execute a handler only when a view is inserted and content is loaded

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I need to execute a handler when two conditions are met:

1. The view associated to an ArrayController is inserted in the DOM
2. The arrayController content is fully loaded, through a store

I tried to add an observer on the `controller.isLoaded` property in the `didInsertElement` but the observer handler never gets called.

```
didInsertElement: function() {
    this.addObserver('controller.isLoaded', function() {
        console.info('inserted the element and store is loaded');
    });
},
```

When I setup the observer outside the `didInsertElement` method, the observer calls too soon the handler, before the view is inserted in the dom.

```
handler: function() {        
    var content, controller = this.get('controller');
    console.info(controller.get('content').get('isLoaded'));
}.observes('controller.isLoaded')
```

Also, I don't understand why the handler in the above scenario gets called twice and each time the controller.get('content') shows an empty array

Answer (score 1):

Possible answer: You may find [my solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13857859/489116) a good fit. The idea is to add a `{{trigger}}` handlebars helper that fires an event when a *subsection* of the view template is rendered. E.g., if you already have a block in your template like `{{#if content.isLoaded}}`, you can do this:

```
{{#if content.isLoaded}}
    {{#each content}}
        ...
    {{/each}}
    {{trigger contentDidRender}}
{{else}}
    <p>Loading...</p>
{{/if}}
```

And you should always get an event when the data displays. Since the handlebars templates already accomplish this pretty well, I just leveraged that.

As for why you're having problems with the things you've tried, you probably have a race condition between the view displaying and the content loading (it is undefined which may happen first)--i.e. you may have added the observer on `isLoaded` after it had already loaded, therefore you did not observe a change. And note that (I think) an `observes` handler gets called each time the observed property gets *set*, not each time it is *changed*... so it could be that it's being set twice but both times to false.

Comment: Quite an effort you put into this. Good for you. Even though this can be quite useful in times, i feel Emberjs should internally trigger an event signalling that the view and its children are fully loaded and another one when the view is rendered and populated if it's bound to an array (RecordArray, Array ..). the content.isLoaded doesn't seem to do the trick for me at least. I find myself forced to go to the drawing board and incorporate into my design the whole Future/Promise Pattern.

Comment: By the way, you solution still doesn't solve my problem. I'm using a jquery plugin to sort a table. The plugin requires the data in the DOM by the time you call upon the sorting method. content.isLoaded = true doesn't guarantee the data is loaded into the view.

Comment: "i feel Emberjs ... if if's bound to an array": Ah, but views are often not that simple--what about your loading indicator (if you have one)--that's not connected to your array...so do you notify when that renders? Really, it's impossible to tell when the rendering of the view is "complete", because it arguably never is--case in point, you can add something to your array and then it renders into the view! Point being, if only it were that easy. One possibility would be to fire and event every time the view changed--which might be useful, but only limitedly so.

Comment: As for not solving the problem, hmm...So is `isLoaded` true before the data is loaded, or does it never become true? There is also `isUpdating`--I've not yet figured out the difference between the two...try checking `isUpdating`? Do you have a loading indicator in your view at all, and does that work properly? That's the use case I had in mind with `{{trigger}}`: that you have a loading indicator in part of an `{{#if}}`/`{{else}}`, and you put `{{trigger}}` in the "finished loading" section. If you can't get a loading/done indicator working, lets figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

One more hint instead of a real solution, perhaps in the didInsertElement, the observer is never called since I think it is wrongly defined. (I don't know if it's support key chaining).I would do something like:

```
didInsertElement: function() {
  this.get('controller.content').addObserver('isLoaded', function() {
    console.info('inserted the element and store is loaded');
  });
}
```

If this works, don't forget to remove this observer inside the willDestroyElement hook

Answer (score 0):

I believe the syntax for addObserver requires the second parameter to be the context where your handler will be executed.

```
didInsertElement: function() {
  this.addObserver('controller.isLoaded', this, function() {
    console.info('inserted the element and store is loaded');
  });
}
```

Note the second param is 'this'. Check out the docs for [Observing Property Changes](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Observable.html)