# Proper way to observe ChildViews in Ember?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js, javascript-framework

Here's a [fiddle for this question](http://jsfiddle.net/EsF4R/174/) (make sure you have your console open):

Basically, I have a handlebars block view as a parent, then loop through an array of items and create child block views for each item. Later, those children are modified in some way, and I want to detect and handle that event.

Summary Code:

```
{{#view App.outerView}}
    {{#each item in items}}
        <h6>Person:</h6>
        {{#view App.innerView}}
            <dl>
                <dt>First Name</dt><dd>{{item.first}}</dd>
                <dt>Last Name</dt><dd>{{item.last}}</dd>
            </dl>
        {{/view}}
    {{/each}}
{{/view}}
```

At some later point:

```
controller.get( 'items' ).pushObject( 'new item' );
```

In the jsFiddle, I am trying to keep the last child object always highlighted (active = true). When the outerView is initially inserted, we apply the highlight to the last item and it works as expected. Later, when we add a new item, our highlight method fires, but it doesn't see the new item.

2 Questions about this:

- **Main Question**: Why doesn't the last item (Matt) get highlighted? In other words, why, after a new item has been added, does `childViews.length` still report the old value? Is there a better way to be doing this?
- **Secondary Question**: Why does the observer on `childViews` fire twice when we add the new item? (3 times total: 1 on initial insert, 2 from addition of 1 new child item)

---

**Edit**: I've adjusted the fiddle a little to better illustrate my needs. Notice the mixed content of the outerView (HTML + innerViews). Basically, my outerView needs to accept ANY content as children, not just an array/collection of views/data.

**Edit 2**: Further clarification: Manipulating those child views after the fact is a different story and can be accomplished either by working with the contents of `childViews` (ember views) or using jQuery to manipulate HTML elements that may not be a formal ember view object, or any other means. *The real goal here is simply to capture the event when ANY of the outerView content changes (with a current copy of childViews).*

**Edit 3**: Here's an [Issue on Github](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2355)

Comment: That is odd that the outer view is not getting it's childViews updated . You could accomplish what you have right now with a CollectionView but that may not serve your purpose? Here is a fiddle for that way http://jsfiddle.net/3Up2M/

Comment: @geekingreen Thanks for this fiddle. It shows things working exactly how I would have expected mine to work. However, in this particular case, I need to be able to use a block view rather than an array binding. Not sure if there are ways to make your example work that way or not.

Comment: i think u r doing wrong...did u try using ContainerView???

Comment: What is probably happening is that the childViews are actually children of an intermediary virtual view, and you're seeing a stale copy of your childViews array because they are not, actually, your childViews. Question is why is the observer firing, then? Hmmmm.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the foobar observer, and examine the actual childView in this._childViews, you can see that this._childViews[0]._childViews includes the newly created yet unrendered name, but this._childViews[0].childViews does not. Yet it is the latter that should be influencing your outerView's childViews property, not the former. Curious.

Comment: So from my investigation it appears that the childViews change notification is originating NOT from the EachView, as we would expect it to, but from the creation of the metamorph view for Matt, which notifies the outerView that its childViews array has changed because the metamorph view for Matt has its parentView set to the outerView, even though it is in fact the intermediary virtual EachView that is handling the rendering. As such, outerView gets told that its childViews property has changed, which is dependent on the EachView's childViews property which has NOT yet changed. Phew.

Comment: long story short... use `{{collection}}`.

Comment: @ChristopherSwasey use `{{collection}}` where?

Comment: I mean you should follow @geekingreen's approach. There's no way this approach is going to work ATM.

Comment: Hrmmm. That's not an option. I need to use a block view that accepts any HTML children.

Answer (score 1):

You initial code looks a little tangled up. Here is a better way to achieve the same result:

http://jsfiddle.net/XaN8T/1/

You should wrap each item in a controller, which is easily done with the `{{each}}` helper:

```
<script data-template-name="application" type="text/x-handlebars">
    This is a list:
    <ul>
        {{each controller itemController="item" itemViewClass="App.ItemView"}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

And create a separate template for your items:

```
<script data-template-name="item" type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h6>Person:</h6>
    <div {{bindAttr class=":content active"}}>
        <dl>
            <dt>First Name</dt><dd>{{first}}</dd>
            <dt>Last Name</dt><dd>{{last}}</dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
</script>
```

Then you can take advantage of [`needs`](http://darthdeus.github.com/blog/2013/01/27/controllers-needs-explained/) and computed properties in Ember with the `active` property:

```
App.ItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['application'], //This way each ItemController can access the ApplicationController's content (i.e. the list of all items)
    active: function() {
        return this.get('controllers.application.lastObject') === this.get('content');
    }.property('controllers.application.lastObject')
});
```

The `App.ItemView` then binds its css class to the controller's `active` property:

```
App.ItemView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    templateName: 'item',
    classNameBindings: ['controller.active']
});
```

Voila! It works :)

Comment: This looks very promising :) I have never seen `needs` before. I don't have time to play with this right now, but I look forward to getting to it. Thank you!!

Comment: Obviously haven't played with this to explore it, but what if we needed to do something more complex than just a class binding? Maybe we need to revalidate a form whenever the childViews change, or... I don't know. Would this approach still work?

Answer (score 0):

A better way of doing what you have accomplished in the fiddle is by the use of [Ember.CollectionView](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.CollectionView.html)

and then adding a computed property which determines whether the child is the last one or not on the `itemViewClass` for the `active` class

```
active: function () {
  return this.get("elementId") === this.get("parentView.childViews.lastObject.elementId");
}.property('parentView.childViews.length'),
```

Here is a   [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EsF4R/172/)

**Note** Whenever there is a need to deal with collection of views either use `CollectionView` or [Ember.ContainerView](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ContainerView.html)(This gives much more control over the child views manipulation) as per your requirements, but for most of the cases `Ember.CollectionView` would suffice

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! I've edited the question to contain some additional information from the comments. Your solution here is perfect, except for one thing: I need to be able to have ANY HTML as children of the outerView.

Comment: so by "any html" you mean the outerView must have different child views and however the last one should have that "active" class ?

Comment: Please see the updated fiddle (sorry, took a little longer than I expected to get it up). Basically, the outerView contents need to be anything that's passed in. Could be all views, could be all HTML, could be mixed.

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760733/ember-js-using-a-handlebars-helper-to-detect-that-a-subview-has-rendered/13857859#13857859