# Observing childViews.@each to implement Select2 with Ember

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to write a Select2View to use with Ember. The main difficulty is that Select2 copies data out of the `option` elements, so we have to inform it whenever we change them. I've got it mostly working, by making the OptionView non-virtual and then observerving `childViews.@each.label` in the Select2View.

I noticed it stopped working when a removed a debug print that was calling `this.get('childViews')` in the observer. With that call, everything works as expected. Without it, the observer is never called even when the child views' labels change. Here is a JSFiddle demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/sYCaS/6/.

Am I doing something wrong here, or is this a bug? I would expect to be able to observe a property of all my child views and be notified when they change.

EDIT: It looks like this behavior is expected, and described here: http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/08/29/ember-1-0-rc8.html#toc_unconsumed-computed-properties-do-not-trigger-observers. However, moving the `get` to `init` as suggested doesn't work. Is `init` called to early in this case or something?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but...

I used the handlebar helper from this SO post:

[Ember.js - Using a Handlebars helper to detect that a subview has rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760733/ember-js-using-a-handlebars-helper-to-detect-that-a-subview-has-rendered/13857859#13857859)

It lets you trigger an action on your view from your template. so by placing it in your subview rendering block you would know when its rendered and you can apply your `select2()`