# How to be notified when a view's template is (re)rendered in Ember?

Tags: javascript, view, ember.js

When a view's template is refreshed due to changes of the model, the `didInsertElement` hook is not triggered as Ember tries to reuse views as much as possible. This causes some problems for me in that I need to select the first element of a list when the template is rerendered. This happens, for example, when new data is loaded from the server or the application transitions to a different route.

The odd thing is that the view's `init` method does get called when the application transitions to a different route. The issue is that the template hasn't been rendered at that point, that is, the view hasn't been populated with the new contents of the controller.

**In short, how can I be notified *after* the template of a view has finished rerendering so that I can manipulate the view's contents?**

For your information, observing the controller's model is not an option either as the view hasn't been updated by the time the callback is fired.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="list">
<div>
  <ul>
  {{#each model.items}}
    <li class="item">
      <p>{{title}}</p>
    </li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>
</script>
```

**Update** The view needs to be notified when the `each` block is rerendered. I wanted to use the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760733/ember-js-using-a-handlebars-helper-to-detect-that-a-subview-has-rendered/13857859#13857859), but it seems that only the `each` block is rerendered and not the entire template (which is what I want). I could add a trigger event in the each block, but that is very expensive as the custom event would be triggered in each loop of the `each` block.

Comment: Can you show the code of the view/template that you want to know when is rerendered?

Comment: Ember just rerender the portions of html where the change is performed, so if your {{#each}} is changing, just the `EachView` instance will receive a rerender event, not the entire `App.ListView`. This is one of the optimisations provided for ember.

Comment: @MárcioRodriguesCorreaJúnior I understand, but how can the `ListView` be notified when the `EachView` is rerendered?

Comment: Give a look in my answer, maybe could help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this could work:

```
App.ListView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'list',
    contentChanged: function() {
        Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, 'selectFirstElement')
    }.observes('controller.content.[]'),
    selectFirstElement: function() {
        // for simplicity
        this.$('li:first').addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Using `observes('controller.content.[]')` make the `contentChanged` function be called, if some change is performed in the controller content. To don't get that function called a lot of times in the same runloop we use the `Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', ...)`, so `selectFirstElement` is called just once, and because it's scheduled in the `afterRender` queue, you can manipule the dom.

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/4b2V3/

Comment: This is brilliant. It definitely isn't a straightforward solution, but it works great especially with the `scheduleOnce` addition.

Answer (score 0):

```
App.MagicView = Ember.View.extend({
  doMagic: function() {
    // magic goes here
  }.on('didInsertElement');
});
```

**Update**: I see now. Here's my brain dump: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/URidoBi/3/edit. Not the cleanest way, but should get you around the problem.

Comment: This doesn't work because of the reason outlined in the question. The `didInsertElement` hook is not invoked when the view's template is rerendered. Ember will reuse a view if it can, which means that the `didInsertElement` hook is not by definition invoked when a view is rerendered.