# Accessing parent view in Handlebars helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to modify [Dockyard's ember-easyForm](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-easyForm) so the model path is saved in the form view rather than the template so you can have multiple forms in a template. I can get the child views to access the parent view but the input-field helper sets up the model path for it's associated view and I'm wondering how can I get access to the parent view from the helper.

```
form-for helper -> Form view (have set formForModelPath property on this view)
  input helper -> Input view
    input-field helper -> TextField, TextArea, Checkbox etc. view
```

The model path is setup in input-field helper, how can I get access to Form.formForModelPath from there?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760733/ember-js-using-a-handlebars-helper-to-detect-that-a-subview-has-rendered), this seems to be the way to access the parent view within a helper:

```
options.data.view.get('parentView');
```

Though in the end I only need to access the view. [Here are my changes](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-easyForm/issues/96) to get ember-easyForms to handle multiple forms on a template.